# How to search string in Event Viewer XML Query?

Tags: windows, event-log, event-viewer

**Hello**, in this section i want to know how to filter an event which contain Data with some words, for example:

**Right Syntax:**

```
*[EventData[Data[@Name='SourceAddress'] ='192.168.1.2']]
```

result: search all Events which Source Address  = 192.168.1.2.

but i want to search all Events which contain LIKE `192.168.`

**Wrong Syntax:**

```
*[EventData[Data[@Name='SourceAddress'] Like '192.168.']]
```

Comment: I think you may need to use PowerShell for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671194/using-xpath-starts-with-or-contains-functions-to-search-windows-event-logs

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to search all Events which contain LIKE 192.168.

Unfortunately I don't think that is directly possible, because:

> Windows Event Log supports a subset of XPath 1.0. There are [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996910(VS.85).aspx#limitations) to what functions work in the query. For instance, you can use the "position", "Band", and "timediff" functions within the query but other functions like "starts-with" and "contains" are not currently supported.

Source [Advanced XML filtering in the Windows Event Viewer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer/)

However, as [w32sh](https://superuser.com/users/542839/w32sh) pointed out in a comment, it is possible with PowerShell. See this Stack Overflow question: [Using XPath starts-with or contains functions to search Windows event logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671194/using-xpath-starts-with-or-contains-functions-to-search-windows-event-logs)